# How to save image to specific folder using HTTP POST method in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How to save an image to the specific folder using HTTP POST method in asp.net c#?
This is my front-end page and I want to get an image in the C# page which can be saved to the specific folder.

I tried "Request.Files["value_resource_image"]" in c# page but its not working!

Thank You!

```
        <form role="form" method="post"  action="post.aspx"  id="form2"  >
           <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Resource ID</label>
              <asp:TextBox ID="value_resource_id" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" class="form-control" required="true"  maxlength="110" placeholder="Enter Resource ID"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label>Resource Name</label>
              <asp:TextBox ID="value_resource_name" runat="server" class="form-control" required="true"  maxlength="110" placeholder="Enter Resource Name"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label>Resource Type</label>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="value_resource_type" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" class="form-control" required="true"  maxlength="110" placeholder="Enter Resource Type">

            </asp:DropDownList>  </div>



     <div class="form-group">
              <label>Category</label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="value_resource_category" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" class="form-control" required="true"  maxlength="110" placeholder="Enter Category">

            </asp:DropDownList> </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
    <label>Sub-Category</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="value_resource_sub_category" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" class="form-control" required="true"  maxlength="110" placeholder="Enter Category">

            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Resource Description</label>
              <asp:TextBox ID="value_resource_description" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Resource Description"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label>Auther</label>
              <asp:TextBox ID="value_resource_auther" runat="server" class="form-control" required="true"  maxlength="110" placeholder="Enter Resource Auther"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label>Publisher</label>
              <asp:TextBox ID="value_resource_publisher" runat="server" class="form-control" required="true"  maxlength="110" placeholder="Enter Resource Publisher"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label>Resource Quantity</label>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="value_resource_quantity" runat="server" class="form-control" required="true"  maxlength="110" placeholder="Enter Resource Quantity"></asp:TextBox>

            </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label>Image</label>
                  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                   <asp:PlaceHolder ID="resource_image_modal" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
           </div><asp:FileUpload ID="value_resource_image" style="margin-top:50px;" runat="server" /></div>
          </div>

                <div class="form-group">
              <label>Status</label>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="value_status" runat="server" class="form-control" required  maxlength="110" placeholder="Enter Date of Birth">

              </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>


                </div>
```

Close

Comment: This is webforms code! (it has nothing to do with asp.net-mvc or asp.net-web-api)

Comment: Do you have any solution to save image to specific folder using HTTP POST method in asp.net c# ?